# How to switch to new scenes without an Mouse/Drag/etc. event?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

In my code I can switch to another scene using buttons like this:

```
public void handleButtonClick(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent menu_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML/FXMLmm2.fxml"));
        Scene SceneMenu = new Scene(menu_parent);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(SceneMenu);
        stage.show();
}
```

Now I have a method in the controller class which should open a scene without an event:

```
public void showResult(boolean win) throws IOException {
        if (win == true) {
            Parent menu_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML/FXMLWinScreen.fxml"));
            Scene SceneMenu = new Scene(menu_parent);
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(SceneMenu);
            stage.show();
        }
```

The problem is, I don't know how to get the node for the stage, this program is only working when I open a whole new stage/window.

How can I switch to a new Scene without an events and opening a new stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any `@FXML` injected node from your controller class,

Let's say you have a button

```
@FXML private Button show;
```

Now use that button `show.getParent().getScene().getWindow()` to get the current stage,

```
public void showResult(boolean win) throws IOException {
    if (win == true) {
        Parent menu_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass()
                               .getResource("/FXML/FXMLWinScreen.fxml"));
        Scene SceneMenu = new Scene(menu_parent);
        Stage stage = (Stage)show.getParent().getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(SceneMenu);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

But make SURE that `showResult` executes after the controller initialization and the node is injected.

Comment: The problem is that this scene doesn't contain any Buttons, just a Gridpane with Imageviews in it. Do you mean with the show Button, a dummy Button which is invisible for the User and can only be activated by the showResult() Method?

Comment: *dummy button?* NO! I meant to use ANY INJECTED node that means annotated with `@FXML`. In your case, it seems you have injected image-view and gridpane. You can use any of them. You can update your question with `@FXML` variables - so that I can reflect in my answer